# Django forms, many to many relations and array field results with resulting square braces

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms

I have this model containing a M2M relationship:

```
class Plane(models.Model):

    ...

    start_types = models.ManyToManyField(StartType, related_name='planes')

class StartType(models.Model):

    ...

    name = models.CharField(max_length=16, verbose_name=_('Name'))
```

From this, I generate a form where the start_types field is represented by a select multiple (select2).
I do this manually, not with Django forms, so I'm not sure how it's solved in Django forms, but my problem lies in Django code, so please bear with me for a moment:

When this form is sent filled-out from browser back to server, I do a jQuery PUT AJAX request. jQuery, seeing that value is an array, also modifies field name in the PUT request by adding square braces after field name, like so: `start_types[]`

I debugged the code and saw that `django.utils.MultiValueDict` has no knowledge of such encoding and will return an empty list for data encoded this way.

So my current workaround is to simply query for `start_types[]` as well and only if that one doesn't return a value, I use the default functionality (without the braces).

This is not the first time I ran into this issue, so at this point I thought it a good idea to ask these two questions:

1. Is this intentionally written so in Django code? Or would an issue / PR be in order?
2. Should I instruct jQuery to use "traditional" mode for encoding form data instead?

Comment: Yes you should use traditional mode. Wouldn't that simply fix your issue entirely?

Comment: Yes, it does fix the issue. However, jQuery documentation mentions more than just field naming in documentation about traditional mode: specifically, it mentions sub-objects and similar stuff. Traditional mode supposedly doesn't support that.